# Switching controllers and sending data in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I have to devellop an internal web based application with codeigniter and I need to chain different forms (generate upon data choosen with previous form).
Right now, I tried to use form validation in the same method of the controller but the chaining only validate the first form, I tried also with $_SESSION variables but I have to send a large amount of data between each form. I tried with class variable (in controllers and models) but every time the form is send the variable are initialise...
So i wonder if there is a way to switch from a method to another one in my controller giving the data to the new controller.

my first form:

```
<p>Filtres: </p>

        <br/><br/>
        <form action="" method="post" id="form_ajout_manip" >
        <label for="thematique[]">Thématique</label><br/>
        <select name="thematique[]" size="20" multiple>
        <?php
            foreach($list_thema->result() as $thema)
            {
                echo "<option value='".$thema->THEMATIQUE_ID."'>".$thema->PARENT_THEMATIQUE_ID." - ".
                $thema->NOM."</option>";
            }
        ?>

        </select>
        <input type="hidden" value="true"/>

        <br/>
        <br/>

        <br/>

            <input type="submit" value="Rechercher" />
        </form>
```

my second form:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="form_ajout_manip_cdt">
<label for="nom_manip" >Nom manipulation: </label>
<br/>
<input type="text" name="nom_manip"/>

<TABLE border="1">

  <CAPTION><?php echo $data->num_rows.'  '; ?>resuuultat</CAPTION>
  <TR>
    <?php
    foreach($data->list_fields() as $titre)
    {
        echo '<TH>'.$titre.'</TH>';
    }
    ?>
  </TR>

<?php
    foreach($data->result() as $ligne)
    {
        echo '<TR>';
        foreach($ligne as $case)
        {
            echo '<TD>'.$case.'</TD>';

        }
        echo '<TD><input type="checkbox" name="cdt[]"  value="'.$ligne->ID_CANDIDAT.'"
                checked="true"</TD>';

        echo '</TR>';
    }
?>

</TABLE>
<br/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="créer"/>
</form>
```

Those are the two method of my controller

```
public function choix()
{
    //controller for the second form
    $this->info_page['title']='Ajout manipulation';
    $this->load->view('ui_items/header',$this->info_page);
    $this->load->view('ui_items/top_menu'); 

    $this->load->view("manipulation/choix",$data);
}

public function filtre()
{
    //controller for the first form

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('thematique[]','Thematique','');
    if($this->form_validation->run())
    {

            $data['data']=$this->manipulation_mod->select_par_filtre($this->input->post('thematique'));
            //need to send $data to the second method "choix()"
    }
    else
    {

        $this->info_page['title']='Filtre ajout manipulation';
        $this->load->view('ui_items/header',$this->info_page);
        $this->load->view('ui_items/top_menu');

        $data= array();
        $data['list_op']= $this->candidat_mod->list_operateur();
        $data['list_thema']= $this->thematique_mod->list_all_thematique();
        $data['list_gene']= $this->candidat_mod->list_gene();

        $this->load->view('manipulation/filtre', $data);
    }
}
```

Have you any idea? I totally stuck...

Comment: I am not sure I got your question right. Are these two forms on two different pages? What data do you want to pass between your controllers?

Comment: In the first one, you choose witch category of items you wants. The second one take the list of items id and request for all information in those items. Then it will save the list of items define by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your clarification, let me give you an outline on what will work

### View

Have both the forms in the same page

```
<? if(!$filtered): ?>

<input type="hidden" name="filtered" value="true"/>
/*  Form 1 content here  */

<? else: ?>
<input type="hidden" name="filtered" value="true"/>
/*  Form 2 content here */

<? endif; ?>
```

### Controller

You just need to use one controller

```
public function filter() {

    $filtered = $this->input->post('filtered');
    $data['filtered'] = $filtered;

    if(empty($filtered)) {
        /*  Form validation rules for Form 1    */
        /*  Run form validation etc. */
        /*  Set title etc. for Form 1   */
    } else {
        /*  Form validation rules for Form 2    */            
        /*  Run form validation etc. */
        /*  Set title etc. for Form 2   */        
    }

    /*  Load view  */
}
```

There might just be a better way to do this, but I am sure this will work. Good luck!